# Use colspan on a single row

Tags: html, layout, html-table

I am trying to get a certain table layout:

```
---------
| |   | |
---------
```

as shown in the first table but would like to only display the row, not the table header. As soon as I hide it, the layout (colspan=2) gets "lost":

```
----------
|  |  |  |
----------
```

Sample code:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <thead style="display:fixed">
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>A</td>
    <td colspan="2">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br/>

<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <thead style="display:none">
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>A</td>
    <td colspan="2">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8v6enhq2/

Comment: The `colspan` attribute is used to merge cells that would normally appear separately. By removing the header cells (which served as reference to the width of the `colspan`), the table is collapsed into three equal-width columns. I think what you'd be better off using here would simply be a `width` attribute or a CSS class that controls the widths of each cell.

Comment: Unfortunately (if I understand your solution correctly) this does not have the same effect: jsfiddle.net/8v6enhq2/2 Also I would prefer a solution based on colspan as the width solution requires me to know the number of cells (and total width) upfront

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but maybe try `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`? That may allow the browser to still consider the header without actually rendering it.

Comment: Here is one way: https://jsfiddle.net/8v6enhq2/16/

Comment: ...and here another: https://jsfiddle.net/8v6enhq2/17/ ... this is the best, though has some cross browser support issues for `collapse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the best fitting answer in my opinion was given in a comment to my initial question by user LGSon, I add it here to accept it as an answer:

Here is one way: jsfiddle.net/8v6enhq2/16 – LGSon 2 days ago

...and here another: jsfiddle.net/8v6enhq2/17 ... this is the best, though has some cross browser support issues for collapse – LGSon 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

The colspan is not lost. The browser is taking the visible cells and determining how wide to make them because no widths were specified. (Essentially it does it's best to distribute the width based on the longest value in each column - though each browser implements this slightly differently)

If you want each cell to consume say 25% of the width, specify it in the cols section.

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <cols>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
  </cols>
  <thead style="display:none">
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>A</td>
    <td colspan="2">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately (if I understand your solution correctly) this does not have the same effect: 

https://jsfiddle.net/8v6enhq2/2/

Also I would prefer a solution based on colspan as the width solution requires me to know the number of cells (and total width) upfront.

Comment: How wide do you want each column to be? If you actually want 2 tables, BOTH with the same width columns, you'll need to set up the widths on both tables to get a match.

Comment: I actually want the cells in the row to align with an evenly distributed header row, but not display the header row. Basically, i want exactly the behaviour of my the first table in my example but have the thead not show.

Comment: Ah, OK I understand now.  The challenge is that you won't be able to get this as the first table has no widths specified for the columns... thus the column widths are arbitrary... as such trying to make another table match an arbitrary table won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <cols>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
  </cols>
  <thead style="display:fixed">
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td  style="width:25%">A</td>
    <td colspan="2">B</td>
    <td  style="width:25%">C</td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <cols>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
    <col style="width:25%"/>
  </cols>
  <thead style="display:none">
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td  style="width:25%">A</td>
    <td colspan="2">B</td>
    <td  style="width:25%">C</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```